# Not able to create DSN for oracle 12c in windows 10

Tags: java, oracle, odbc, windows-10, jdbc-odbc

I want to run my JDBC application jdk(1.7) with jdbcOdbc Bridge Driver(Type - 1 Driver). I am using Oracle 12C and windows 10 OS.

I am getting this error massage when I am trying to register DSN.

> Oracle client and networking components were not found

I have check path variable its working fine. But still getting this error.

Comment: Use the Oracle JDBC driver, don't use the JDBC ODBC bridge, it is buggy and has been removed with Java 8. In any case, if you insist on using the JDBC ODBC bridge: your question has little to do with Java or JDBC, as you seem to have a problem with defining the ODBC DSN.

Comment: @mark makes a great point. Can you expand on the requirement to use ODBC with the Java application? Are there specific features in ODBC that you're not getting in JDBC?

Comment: Thank you @mark for your replay.. I am new to JDBC, I am learning from beginning, so for learning purpose and understanding the draw back I want to use ODBC bridge driver. if you can help me fix the bug I will be great-full

Comment: You really **should not use** the JDBC/ODBC bridge. Period. It is harder to use, buggy, and removed in newer Java versions. Use a 'normal' JDBC driver. And again, your problem has nothing to do with Java/JDBC, you are stuck at creating the ODBC DSN, which indicates you haven't installed some parts of the Oracle ODBC driver or client libraries.